# Simplest method to Select all columns in a table with distinct condition on one column

Tags: sql, distinct

I have a table with more than 100 columns, I want to write a select query that picks all the columns from the table based on distinct condition on one column.

```
For ex->

Col_A Col_B Col_C Col_D
  1     120  12     12
  1     12   43     23
  1      3    1      1
  2     12    1     132
  2     13    3     333
```

In the above example, I want to pick all columns where Col_A is unique(First occurrence in the case where multiple values are present in the source table)

```
Output

Col_A Col_B Col_C Col_D
  1     120  12     12
  2     12    1     132
```

Comment: Please tag your specific database platform. There is no "first" row in your sample data, you need some additional column by which to specify an ordering criteria to determin which row is "first".

Answer (score 0):

If `distinct on` syntax is supported, you can do like:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT ON (Col_A) * FROM table_name
```

Alternatively, if window function is supported, something like below will achieve that.
The tmp subquery assign incremental numbers separately by Col_A values,
and the main query picks only those the first record.

```sql
with tmp as (
  SELECT *, row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY Col_A) AS num
  FROM table_name
)
SELECT * FROM tmp WHERE num=1
```

More ideas can be found if you specify the sql dialect you are working with.

Comment: Row number requires an `order by` clause.

Comment: That depends on the sql engine. Some admits omitting `order by` and generate numbers in a random order.